# Javascript slideshow with random first pic?

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, slideshow

I'm trying to setup this slideshow script so that the first pic that shows is random (I need the first pic to be a different/random slide everytime we go to the site), the remaining pics can be displayed in the right order, that's fine.

I'm using Jon Raasch's simple jquery slideshow script, here it goes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow DIV.active');
    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow DIV:last');
    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
        : $('#slideshow DIV:first');
    $active.addClass('last-active');
    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}
$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 2500 );
});
</script>

<div id="slideshow">
<div class="active"><img src="images/slide1.jpg"></div>
<div><img src="images/slide2.jpg"></div>
<div><img src="images/slide3.jpg"></div>
<div><img src="images/slide4.jpg"></div>
<div><img src="images/slide5.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#slideshow {
position:relative;
height:401px;
}
#slideshow div {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:8;
opacity:0.0;
}
#slideshow div.active {
z-index:10;
opacity:1.0;
}
#slideshow div.last-active {
z-index:9;
}
```

I've tried a few things but javascript really isn't my cup of tea ("designer-mind" here) and what I've tried is not working. Any ideas?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on jfriend00's answer, you need to set your script to this:

```
 function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow div.active');
    if ( $active.length == 0 ) {
    var slides = $('#slideshow div');
    $active = slides.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * slides.length));
}
    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
        : $('#slideshow div:first');
    $active.addClass('last-active');
    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}
$(function() {
    slideSwitch();
    setInterval( function(){slideSwitch()}, 2500 );
});
```

There were some syntax errors and I had to change how the setInterval is being called.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f2UPm/

Comment: Thanks Valuk! Indeed your script works, but only in jsFiddle, although I figured why. I need to have the script work "onLoad", at least that's the option in jsFiddle that made it works. Could you tell me how can I do that with the script?

Comment: Works for me in the fiddle regardless of the jsFiddle onLoad option. Can you post a version of the fiddle where it doesn't? The setInterval is already being called when the document is ready, see http://api.jquery.com/ready/ for more information.

Comment: Nevermind that! Thanks for pointing this out. I'm a worse javascript coder that I thought.

Comment: Any idea how we could have the first slide appears faster? Right now, it's blank (all white), apparently it seems like its waiting for the 2500 milliseconds to go by, then the first random picture appears, then the slideshow follows. I think it's because of the setInterval function. How can I have the first picture loaded without waiting for the setInterval?

Comment: Edited my answer above, just need to call the slideSwitch() function straight away. I should have thought of that earlier, now that we're not starting with an active picture.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the active class from the HTML and then set it initially with this code by changing this line from this and adjust the CSS so no slides are visible until your JS runs:

```
if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow DIV:last');
```

to this:

```
if ( $active.length == 0 ) {
    var slides = $('#slideshow DIV');
    $active = slides.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * slides.length));
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/mpYSL/

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! Unfortunately your code didn't work... it just doesn't show anything. I fixed the '#slideshow DIV" (you must have mistyped) but apparently it still doesn't work...

Comment: @live2create - Then, perhaps your question wasn't clear.  If you follow my instructions to make all slides initially not visible, remove the initial `class="active"` from the HTML, insert this code and then make the slideshow visible after you've run this first block of code, this code will randomly select the starting point.  I thought that's what you were asking for.  If you want further help with your implementation, I would suggest you make a working example in a jsFiddle so we can see where your mistake in implementation is.

Comment: Thanks jfriend00, like I said Javascript isn't my cup of tea. I created a jsFiddle like you suggested, please have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/YPKDm/

Comment: Like you can see it's not showing anything. Here's the original one for you to compare (without the changes you suggested): http://jsfiddle.net/27bqR/

Comment: @live2create - The very first thing you need to learn about javascript is to look for script errors in the error console or debug console.  That will save you enourmous amounts of time.  I had a typo in my answer (an extra paren) and you had a mistake in your jsFiddle.  They are both corrected here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/mpYSL/ and it works.

Comment: @live2create - note, I also removed the quotes around the function name in `setInterval()` as that is a bad practice and was causing problems in your jsFiddle with the settings you had because your function wasn't global.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$(function() {
    var slides, index, current, last, last_index;
    slides = $('#slideshow div');
    // initialize index randomly
    index = Math.floor(Math.rand() * slides.length);
    // do a % trick to get index - 1 looping
    last_index = (index + slides.length - 1) % slides.length;
    last = slices[last_index]; // initialize last

    function slideSwitch() {
        current = slides[index];
        index = (index + 1) % slides.length; // % to loop
        current.addClass("active");
        last.addClass("last-active");
        current.css({ "opacity": 0.0 })
            .animate({ "opacity": 1.0}, 1000, function() {
                current.removeClass("active");
                last.addClass("active");
                last.removeClass("last-active");
                last = current;
            });
    }
    setInterval(slideSwitch, 2500);
    slideShow(); // run once now, because interval doesn't run until 2500ms
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for trying to help! Unfortunately that code didn't work... it just shows the first slide but nothing happens.